.SolrServerException: IOException occurred when talking to server
2
I am using basic authentication. My solr version is 8.11.2. I am getting below exception while indexing solr for transactionId:
20059192046","exception":"org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: IOException occurred when talking to server at:
http://10.2.12.5:8993/solr\n\tat
org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:695)\n\tat org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:266)\n\tat org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:248)\n\tat org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:214)
getting exception while indexing solr for transactionId
